# Why did Kylo Ren attack Quinn in this scene?

Tags: star-wars, kylo-ren, the-rise-of-skywalker

> **Quinn:** *This fleet, what is it, a gift? What is he asking for in
> return?*
>
> [Ren uses the Force to slam him into the ceiling]
>
> **KYLO REN:** *Prepare to crush any worlds that defy us. My knights and I
> are going hunting for the scavenger.*

[image]

Why did Kylo Ren attack Quinn?

Comment: He found his lack of faith disturbing...

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - I've been in business meetings where doing this would have been an absolute joy

Comment: Because there's someone else in the room whose thoughts should be betraying them, and this plot coupon from 43 years ago keeps them and us from poking holes in it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Kylo Ren did not appreciate having his orders questioned.

> **“This fleet,” General Quinn said. “What is it…a gift?”**
>
> **This was the exact question Kylo did not want to answer.**
>
> “What is he asking for in return?” Quinn pressed. “Does he—”
>
> Kylo thrust out his arm, calling on all his anger, all his impatience. General Quinn flew high, slammed into the ceiling. Something in his body fractured loudly, but it didn’t matter if the internal wound was mortal or not because Kylo kept him stuffed against the ceiling, gasping like a fish out of water, gradually choking to death.
>
> Kylo stared his officers down. Hux was visibly shaken. Good. “Prepare to crush any worlds that defy us,” he spat out. “In the meantime, my Knights and I are going hunting for the scavenger.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

Comment: Oh, Kylo Ren and Admiral Holdo graduated from the same officer school.